# Can you style video_player package in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using video_player 0.10.8+1 and everything is working fine but can I decorate the border to show a circular border? For e.g:
`borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(8.0)` as in image `BoxDecoration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can clip the video player, however, you can cover arc object on video player with Stack, [clippy_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this style in a listview of videos if it's possible. 

(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M3aHvtcaJ1S2IgoE1ved90qED2W9Mn76)